# SSRS and Grouping with Null

Tags: reporting-services, grouping

Good Morning
I have a SSRS report with a main group, Vendors, and a secoundary Group of Checks No. when the report runs the check numbers that are null do not show on the report and either does the detail of that null check. I have tried the isnothing expression to see if that would work as the group expression but to no avail.
I have even tried the isnothing expression within the row groups to no avail. All the date from the other groups comes up as long as check number shows.
Can groups even secondary groups show nulls? Am I missing something baisc here.

this is what I Have a my secoundary group: IIF(Isnothing(Fields!Check_No),"", Fields!Check_no)

Help please

I have tried in the expression as the group, or under the row groups expression

IIF(Isnothing(Fields!Check_No),"", Fields!Check_no)

Trying to get the nulls to show

Comment: For a start you need to use `Fields!Check_No.Value`. You need to show a sample of your data with some records that don't have a problem and some that do. Show the report design including the row groups and also your dataset query if relevant. Are you sure the dataset returns these `NULL` records?